# my request code is not printing the body of API

Tags: node.js, api, backend

my request code is not printing api

```
var request = require('request');
request('https://abusiveexperiencereport.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1a', function (error, response, body){
    if(error){
        console.log("something went wrong")
        console.log("error")
    } else{
        if(response.statusCode == 200){
            var data = JSON.parse(Body);
            console.log(data);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Well what is it doing? Have you tried to solve this...

Comment: yes. but did n't find any solution. Actually, it is neither showing any error.

Comment: Well if status code is something else than 200, your code doesn't do anything.

Comment: You are trying to parse `body` with a capital **B**, that would be undefined. `JSON.parse(body)` , that should work assuming body is a valid json string

Answer (score 1):

Use request.get and also give value of $discovery in your request.

```
     request.get('https://abusiveexperiencereport.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest? 
           version=v1a', function (error, response, body){
            if(error){
                console.log("something went wrong")
                console.log("error")
            } else{
                if(response.statusCode == 200){
                       var data = JSON.parse(Body);
                       console.log(data);
                }
            }
         });
```